# Separation Steering Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, generator, unity-game-engine

Ok so this site has helped me alot before i had an account, but now the net is not helping me so i'll post it myself :)

I am looking (i am yet another one) to do something like this:
tinykeep.com/dungen/

Now the first step(Generating the rooms , goes well), but this is the first time ever I encounter Flocking behaviour algorithms, and my maths really arent that terrific.

So i tried and came up with a non working algorithm, what i did is started from next standard separation algorithm: gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-three-simple-rules-of-flocking-behaviors-alignment-cohesion-and-separation--gamedev-3444 (sorry for this text but it wouldn't let me post more than 2 links without 10 rep), And changed it to my liking. Like i said before it's really not doing anything, if i find how i'll post some debug results.

Here's my code:

```
class Room {

Vector3 position;
Vector3 size;
int area;

public Room(Vector3 position, Vector3 size, int area) : this(position, size){

    this.area = area;

}

public Room(Vector3 position, Vector3 size){

    this.position = position;
    this.size = size;
    if(area != null)
        this.area = (int)(size.x * size.z);

}

public Vector3 GetPosition(){

    return position;

}

public Vector3 GetSize(){

    return size;

}

public void SetPosition(Vector3 position){

    this.position = position;

}

public Boolean TooCloseTo(Room room){

    return position.x + size.x / 2 > room.GetPosition().x - room.GetSize().x / 2 || position.z + size.z / 2 > room.GetPosition().z - room.GetSize().z / 2 ||
        position.x - size.x / 2 < room.GetPosition().x + room.GetSize().x / 2 || position.z - size.z / 2 < room.GetPosition().z + room.GetSize().z / 2;

}

public override string ToString ()
{
    return string.Format ("[Room]\nPosition:{0}\nSize:{1}\nArea:{2}", position, size, area);
}

}
```

These are part of the Mapgenerator class, the rest of this class works fine and seems unimportant to me, but if you feel the need to see it, let me know and i'll post it.

```
void SeparateRooms(){

    foreach (Room room in rooms) {

        //Debug.Log (room);
        Vector3 oldPos = room.GetPosition ();
        Vector3 separation = computeSeparation (room);
        //Debug.Log (separation);
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3 (oldPos.x += separation.x, oldPos.y, oldPos.z += separation.z);
        room.SetPosition (newPos);
        //Debug.Log (room);

    }

}

Vector3 computeSeparation(Room agent) {

    int neighbours = 0;
    Vector3 v = new Vector3 ();

    foreach (Room room in rooms) {

        if (room != agent) {

            if (agent.TooCloseTo (room)) {

                v.x += Difference(room, agent, "x");
                v.z += Difference(room, agent, "z");
                neighbours++;

            }

        }

    }

    if (neighbours == 0)
        return v;

    v.x /= neighbours;
    v.z /= neighbours;
    v.x *= -1;
    v.z *= -1;
    v.Normalize ();
    return v;

}

float Difference(Room room, Room agent, string type){

    switch (type) {

    case "x":
        float xBottom = (room.GetPosition ().x + room.GetSize ().x / 2) - (agent.GetPosition ().x - agent.GetSize ().x / 2);
        float xTop = (agent.GetPosition ().x + agent.GetSize ().x / 2) - (room.GetPosition ().x - room.GetSize ().x / 2);
        return xBottom > 0 ? xBottom : xTop;
        break;
    case "z":
        float xRight= (room.GetPosition ().z + room.GetSize ().z / 2) - (agent.GetPosition ().z - agent.GetSize ().z / 2);
        float xLeft= (agent.GetPosition ().z + agent.GetSize ().z / 2) - (room.GetPosition ().z - room.GetSize ().z / 2);
        return xRight > 0 ? xRight : xLeft;
    default:
        return 0;
        break;

    }

}
```

I was expecting the difference to be numbers like 4.0 and 8.0 and so on, instead i get 0.9 and 0.3 and so on, i'll copy an output:
[Debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKonW.png)

I hope that is readable.
Explanation: Each three lines are the info about the room:
    1. the original room
    2. the (what's supposed to be the) overlap between the room and the next
    3. the new position of the room

EDIT: Ok thanks to the comments i'm getting pretty normal results for overlap now, but the rooms are still overlapping after i run the algorithm, i think this might have to do something with only iterating once over every room... Any comments on that?

I really hope some of you might be able to point me in the right direction, or tell me what is wrong in my reasoning.

Thank you!

EDIT: Filling up rooms:

```
public void Generate(int level) {

    int levelModifier = (int)(Math.Round ((double)Mathf.Log (level, 2.5f),1) * 10);
    int mean = 25;
    int SD = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30 + levelModifier; i++) {

        Vector3 position = getPInCircle (20);

        int area = (int)SimpleRNG.GetNormal (mean, SD);
        if (area < mean - SD)
            continue;

        Vector3 size = calculateSize (area);

        Room room = new Room (position, size);

        rooms.Add (room);

    }

    SeparateRooms ();


}

Vector3 calculateSize(int area) {

    float k = UnityEngine.Random.Range (2.0f, area / 2.0f);
    float l = area / k;
    int shortSide;
    int longSide;
    if (Mathf.Round (k) > Mathf.Round (l)) {

        shortSide = Mathf.RoundToInt (k);
        longSide = Mathf.RoundToInt (l);

    } else {

        shortSide = Mathf.RoundToInt (l);
        longSide = Mathf.RoundToInt (k);

    }

    //Debug.Log (shortSide);
    //Debug.Log (longSide);

    Vector3 size;

    if (SimpleRNG.GetUniform () < 0.5) {

        size = new Vector3 (Actualise(shortSide), 0, Actualise(longSide));

    } else {

        size = new Vector3 (Actualise(longSide), 0, Actualise(shortSide));

    }

    return size;

}
```

The SimpleRNG is John D. Cook's Namespace, open for download at www.codeproject.com/Articles/25172/Simple-Random-Number-Generation

Comment: Double-check the code you posted.  It's not formatted correctly, and a section appears to be missing.

Comment: Yeah I only posted the key functions, the ones that do the seperation, and then obviously the room class, and thanks i fixed the formatting now i think

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you're asking.  Additionally, can you show us how `rooms` is being populated, and how you're calling `SeparateRooms()`?

Comment: The info is in an extra edit, i'm guessing the main part of my question is why i'm getting these weird overlap numbers, they are under zero, which really confuses me, because i'm trying to space them out and they all are mashed in one place almost, so the overlap should be way more...

Comment: *"I was expecting the difference to be numbers like 4.0 and 8.0 and so on, instead i get 0.9 and 0.3 and so on"* I think this is caused by the last line before `return` in your `computeSeparation` method - `v.Normalize();`

Comment: Oh shoo you might be right let me test that!

Comment: Thanks i got that fixed now!